# Return only string message from Spring MVC 3 Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can any one tell me how I can return string message from controller?

If i just return a string from a controller method then spring mvc treating it as a jsp view name.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Annotate your method in controller with `@ResponseBody`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/controller", method=GET)
@ResponseBody
public String foo() {
    return "Response!";
}
```

From: [15.3.2.6 Mapping the response body with the `@ResponseBody` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody):

> The `@ResponseBody` annotation [...] can be put on a method and indicates that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name).

Comment: To make it clearer, I would add  _produces="text/plain_ `@RequestMapping(value="/controller", method=GET, produces="text/plain")`

Comment: The real answer is always in the comments.

Answer (score 60):

With Spring 4, if your Controller is annotated with `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`, you don't need the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

The code would be

```
@RestController
public class FooController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/controller", method=GET)
   public String foo() {
      return "Response!";
   }

}
```

You can find the Javadoc for `@RestController` [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out I needed to use \@Controller instead of \@RestController in order to return a view, rather than a String.

Comment: @khriskooper glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 19):

Although, @Tomasz is absolutely right there is another way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/controller", method=GET)
public void foo(HttpServletResponse res) {
    try {       
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello, world!");
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) { 
        ...
    }
}
```

but the first method is preferable. You can use this method if you want to return response with custom content type or return binary type (file, etc...);

Comment: Just a heads up, but you don't even need to pull the response in for this.

Comment: Meant that for the second point, about needing to set a custom content type or returning a binary type, you can still use the ResponseEntity for those means.

Comment: This allows you to return data that might not fit in memory. I don't know if there's a better alternative for that in Spring, but this is generally what I've used.

Answer (score 6):

This is just a note for those who might find this question later, but you don't have to pull in the response to change the content type.  Here's an example below to do just that:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/controller")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> displayUploadedFile()
{
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  String disposition = INLINE;
  String fileName = "";
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

  //Load your attachment here

  if (Arrays.equals(Constants.HEADER_BYTES_PDF, contentBytes)) {
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"));
    fileName += ".pdf";
  }

  if (Arrays.equals(Constants.HEADER_BYTES_TIFF_BIG_ENDIAN, contentBytes)
      || Arrays.equals(Constantsr.HEADER_BYTES_TIFF_LITTLE_ENDIAN, contentBytes)) {
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("image/tiff"));
    fileName += ".tif";
  }

  if (Arrays.equals(Constants.HEADER_BYTES_JPEG, contentBytes)) {
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    fileName += ".jpg";
  }

  //Handle other types if necessary

  headers.add("Content-Disposition", , disposition + ";filename=" + fileName);
  return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(uploadedBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("THE_STRING_TO_SEND_AS_RESPONSE");
return null;
```

This woks for me.

Answer (score 3):

For outputing `String` as `text/plain` use:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/plain")
@ResponseBody
public String foo() {
    return "bar";
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to get the response object and explicitly set the content type before returning the String object.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solution

1. Use `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`, to combine HTML page and the string message for different functions

   ```
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping({ "/user/registration"})
   public class RegistrationController {    
   @GetMapping
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new UserDto());
        return "registration"; //Returns the registration.html
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public String registerUserAccount(@Valid final UserDto accountDto, final HttpServletRequest request) {
        LOGGER.debug("Registering user account with information: {}", accountDto);
        return "Successfully registered" // Returns the string
    }
   ```
2. Use `@RestController` to return String message. In this case, you cannot have functions which returns HTML page.

   ```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping({ "/user/registration"})
    public class RegistrationController {

    @PostMapping
        public String registerUserAccount(@Valid @RequestBody final UserDto accountDto, final HttpServletRequest request) {
            LOGGER.debug("Registering user account with information: {}", accountDto);
            return "Successfully registered" // Returns the string
        }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<String> sayHello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest solution:**

Just add quotes, I really don't know why it's not auto-implemented by Spring boot when response type defined as application/json, but it works great.

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public String foo()
{
    String result = "something"
    return "\"" + result + "\"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/get-text", produces="text/plain")
public String myMethod() {
     return "Response!";
}
```

- You see that `@ResponseBody` ?

> It's telling that the method returns some text and not to interpret
> it as a view etc.

- You see that `produces="text/plain"` ?

> It's just a *good practice* as it tells what will be returned from the
> method  :)