# Want my spring controller to return a string without a view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return only string message from Spring MVC 3 Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672858/return-only-string-message-from-spring-mvc-3-controller)

My spring controller has a endpoint where I want to only:

```
1. set the http response code
2. return a string back, don't need to render a .jsp view page or anything.
```

So will want to set the http status code to 200 OK or 500 etc.
And simply return a string like "OK".

How can I do this, or am I forced to render a .jsp view page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `@ResponseBody` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sayHello", method=GET)
@ResponseBody
public String whatever() {
    return "Hello";
}
```

See the [`@ResponseBody` ref docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) for further details.

You may be able to use the `@ResponseStatus` annotation to set the code rather than using the `HttpServletResponse` directly.

Comment: well I'm setting the status depending on the flow of code, thanks.

Comment: @Blankman Yeah, you'll need the `HttpServletResponse` variety then.

Comment: You need to add produces="text/plain" to the @RequestMapping other wise the Content-Type of the response will still remain text/html

Comment: @VivekGiri Which is fine, actually. But it should be added, yes.

Answer (score 13):

No, you are not forced to use view. If you use more recent version of Spring, you may use `@ResponseBody` annotation. See [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for reference.

Example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/plain")
@ResponseBody
public String returnSimpleMessage() {    
    return "OK";
}
```

You could also use HttpServletResponse as a parameter to set desired HTTP status.