# Spring MVC- returning string value from controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to String, and now facing some staring issues with Spring MVC.

In my application I have view resolver which maps view names to respective JSP files.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

It is working as expected, but now need to call a method in controller and show returned string in view.

my URL of request looks like  http://localhost:8015/demo/greet

And the method in my controller to server this request is

```
@RequestMapping("/greet")
    public String user(User user) {
        return "Hi User";

    }
```

When i call this url from browser, given method in browser get invoked, and when it returns a string, `InternalResourceViewResolver` try to find a page `/WEB-INF/pages/greet.jsp`, and as it doesn't exist, user gets `404 error`. How can i send raw String from my controller method to browser?

Comment: Add `@ResponseBody` to the method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672858/return-only-string-message-from-spring-mvc-3-controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your controller code as below

```
@RequestMapping("/greet")
    public @ResponseBody String user(User user) {
        return "Hi User";

    }
```

See documentation of [ResponseBody here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@RequestMapping("/greet")
    public @ResponseBody String user(User user) {
        return "Hi User";
    }
```