# javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new in Spring. And i'm stuck with 'HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception'.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIWPP.png)

Though i have tried looking at every single file still couldn't figure out why is it happening. Below is my code sample.

**Controller.**
`

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class InController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(){
        return "Welcome";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/driver")
    public String driver(){
        return "Driver";
    }
}
```

**waiting-servlet.xml**
`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">




    <context:component-scan base-package="main.java">
    </context:component-scan>


    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <bean id="JSPView"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>JSP/Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>waiting</display-name>
    <servlet-name>waiting</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>waiting</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tcs</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.wicket-jquery-ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery-ui-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cocoon</groupId>
        <artifactId>cocoon-ajax</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return only string message from Spring MVC 3 Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672858/return-only-string-message-from-spring-mvc-3-controller)  That should solve uour problem.

Comment: I want to display jsp pages. and accordingly I have returned the page name as string which will be interpreted  by view resolver. and it should display the JSP page. in my waiting-servlet.xml

Comment: You are mixing versions of spring (4.2.3 and 4.2.4) never do that.

Comment: what would happen if I mix them. one version is evolved from its preceding one. Hence it shouldn't Cause any critical issue