# Springboot hand JSON to frontend

Tags: json, spring-boot, request-mapping

I want to pass a JSON to the client on request. My actual code looks something like this:

```
...
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
...

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Value("classpath:file.json")
    private Resource jsonFile;

    @GetMapping(path ="json", produces = "application/json")
    public String getJSON() {
        try (InputStream in = jsonFile.getInputStream()) {
            return IOUtils.toString(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        }
        catch ...
    }
}

...
```

jsonFile is the .json file whose content i want to send back to the user, the @Value annotation adds the classpath.

The Issue is: the Response is not only the json, but also linebreaks are encodede as `\n` and the entire JSON is encapsulated in quotation marks making it one big string instead of an object. As the JSON is actually a .json file i would not like to parse it into an object first.

jsonFile looks like:

```
{
  "thing1": [
    {
      "list1": [
        "abc"
      ],
      "subthing1": {
        "list1": [
          "aaa",
          "bbb"
        ],
        "list2": [
          "ccc"
        ],
        "list3": [
          "zzz"
        ],

      },
      "subthing2": 
      ...
```

**Edit 1:** [Returning JSON object as response in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839753/returning-json-object-as-response-in-spring-boot) 's answers last paragraph states "If you want to return a json serialized string then just return the string.", which red for me: "if you have a json in a string, return the string"

Comment: what is var? where is it declared?

Comment: You might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672858/return-only-string-message-from-spring-mvc-3-controller

Comment: You are getting string since your code says that.
i.e  return IOUtils.toString(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
Please explain what is var in your code.

Comment: sorry, didn't see what info u missed, hope this is what u asked for?
Also fixed that Class annotation which falsely was ät.RequestController isneatd of correct ät.RestController

Answer (score 0):

Use wriper for String:

```
class StringRespWriper {
    private String stringResponse;
    // get/set
}
```

and return it on controller:

```
@GetMapping(path ="json", produces = "application/json")
public StringRespWriper getJSON() {
    try (InputStream in = var.getInputStream()) {
    ....
}
```